# Determinants inside matrix

Tags: matrices

I am typing in .tex a solution using Cramer method but I can't find a way to write those matrixes inside the main matrix. Is there an easy way to do that?

Comment: Maybe this can help? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50627/matrix-in-a-matrix

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: You should contruct a multi merged matrix. This should help you out: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43656/table-with-multiple-merging

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the solution already... is not that beautiful, but there is an example.

```
enter code here

\[adj(\mathbb{K})= \left[ \def\arraystretch{1.8} \begin{array}{ccc}  
+\begin{vmatrix} \frac{-2r\cos\theta}{R_E\sin^3\theta} &                     0                  \\ 0 & 1 \end{vmatrix}   &
-\begin{vmatrix} \frac{1}{R_E\sin^2\theta}             &                       0                \\ 0 & 1 \end{vmatrix}   &
+\begin{vmatrix} \frac{1}{R_E\sin^2\theta}             & -\frac{-2r\cos\theta}{R_E\sin^3\theta} \\ 0 & 0 \end{vmatrix}   \\
  &&\\
-\begin{vmatrix} \frac{-R^2_E\sin^2\theta}{r^2}        &                 0                      \\ 0 & 1 \end{vmatrix}   &
+\begin{vmatrix} \frac{-2R^2_E\cos\theta}{r^3}         &                 0                      \\ 0 & 1 \end{vmatrix}   &
-\begin{vmatrix} \frac{-2R^2_E\cos\theta}{r^3}         & -\frac{-R_E\sin\theta}{r^2}            \\ 0 & 0 \end{vmatrix}   \\
 &&\\
+\begin{vmatrix} \frac{-R^2_E\sin\theta}{r^2}  &            0   \\ \frac{-2r\cos\theta}{R_E\sin^3\theta}  &    0 \end{vmatrix}  &
-\begin{vmatrix} \frac{-2R^2_E\cos\theta}{r^3} &            0   \\ \frac{1}{R_E\sin^2\theta}              &    0  \end{vmatrix}  &
+\begin{vmatrix} \frac{-2R^2_E\cos\theta}{r^3} &\frac{-R^2_E\sin\theta}{r^2} \\ \frac{1}{R_E\sin^2\theta} & \frac{-2r\cos\theta}{R_E\sin^3\theta}\end{vmatrix}
    \end{array} \right]^T,\]
```

[image: The result]

Comment: A quick hint: if you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they are [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192/5001). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "`{}`" on it).