# Please Help to prepare the following table

Tags: tables, multirow, multicolumn

[image]

Please, Help me inserting a table like this. I could not prepare this table even after using the \multicolumn package. I am facing difficulties with merging the rows and columns. I am in an urgent need. Please Help !

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/5001) You will need to load the `multirow` package, not the `multicol` package.

Comment: Possible duplicate(s): [Table with multiple merging](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/43656/5764); [Combine 4 cells in a table](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35126/5764)

Comment: Thanks @Mico . I have included multirow also that I forgot to mention. Still I could not manage it.

Comment: Thanks @Werner . The links seem helpful. I am new in latex writing. I will learn how to make this type of tables.But, as I am in urgent need and I am new in LaTeX, would you do a favor of me ? Would you please supply the code of the table what exactly I need ?

Comment: Please provide (a lot) more information about the table design you need: Should all eight columns be equally wide, or should just columns 3 through 8 be equally wide, or does it not matter at all how wide the columns are? Should the contents be fully-justified, left-justified, centered, or right-justified? Are you literally going to typeset strings like `aaaaaa`? It that's not the case (and I sincerely hope it's not...), should the text in a cell be allowed to "wrap" to the next line?

Comment: @Mico Thanks for your reply. 

All should be centred. In Column D, I will put some mathematical function in place of "aaaaaa". In a line it is impossible to put the whole function. So wrap to the next line can be allowed for the column D. Otherwise, it does not matter how wide columns are.

Comment: Off-topic: Please start your first latex [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) by copying and tweaking code from duplicates Q's from _today_ so that you will feel and experience better than making others do for you in a hurry. LaTeX is not the right tool for _last minute jobs_ for sure atleast in beginners stage.  Some editors(Texmaker,Texstudio...) have already GUI wizard boxes for table design. Have a quick read at http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables and search tex.sx with `tags`

Answer (score 3):

Here's an implementation of what I understand your requirements are. It uses the `multirow` package and tries to maximize the width of column "D". If more material than currently included shows up in the other columns, the width of column "D" will shrink accordingly. If, in the end, you do not need the table to be as wide as the text block, use some multiple of `\textwidth` less than `1.0` in the first argument of the `tabularx` column definitions.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,multirow}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabularx}{1.0\textwidth}{|c| Y| *{6}{c|} }
\cline{3-8}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{} &  & 
\multicolumn{3}{c|}{A} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{B}\\
\hline
C & D & E & F & G & H & I & J\\
\hline
\multirow{4}{*}{l} &
\multirow{4}{*}{aaaaaa} &
\multirow{2}{*}{bbbb} &
\multirow{2}{*}{cccc} &
\multirow{4}{*}{eeee} &
ffff & hhhh &
\multirow{4}{*}{iiii}\\
& & & & & ffff & hhhh & \\
& & 
\multirow{2}{*}{bbbb} &
\multirow{2}{*}{cccc} & & ffff & hhhh & \\
& & & & & ffff & hhhh & \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Enter the table's caption here}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: How can I do it with the TexStudio wizard?

Comment: @skan - Sorry, no idea. I don't use TeXstudio.

Answer (score 2):

Your tabular might not be easy for  beginner, so for a good start at  TeX.SE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|*8{l|}}
\cline{3-8}
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{3}{c|}{A}&\multicolumn{3}{c|}{B}\\
\hline
C&D&E&F&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{G}&H&I&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{J}\\ % for example G and J centered
\hline
\begin{tabular}{l}
1
\end{tabular}&
\begin{tabular}{l}
aaaa
\end{tabular}&
\begin{tabular}{l}
bbbb\\
{}\\
bbbb
\end{tabular}&
\begin{tabular}{l}
cccc\\
{}\\
cccc
\end{tabular}&
\begin{tabular}{l}
eeee
\end{tabular}&
\begin{tabular}{l}
ffff\\
ffff\\
ffff\\
ffff
\end{tabular}&
\begin{tabular}{l}
hhhh\\
hhhh\\
hhhh\\
hhhh
\end{tabular}&
\begin{tabular}{l}
iiii
\end{tabular}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Przemystaw Scherwenti Thank you very much !

Comment: @Texenthusiast Thanks for your suggestions. Actually seeing the wiki books I could not manage to make the table. However, I will learn and no other than me will be  happier if I can make this type of complex table on my own in future.

Comment: In order to avoid excessive amounts of inter-column whitespace, you may want to use `\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}` rather than simply `\begin{tabular}{l}` for the eight "inner" tabular environments. That, or issue the command `\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}` to reduce the value of that parameter by 50%.

Comment: @Mico Certainly. I would also take rows as a parameter of command; but not too much for a beginner.

Comment: How can I do it with the TexStudio wizard?